# Hanging punching bag from wood plank in basement

Tags: basement, hanging

I am looking to hang a punching bag in the basement of new house we moved in to. There is a drop ceiling and above that there are joists and 2x4 boards attached to the joists. Not sure of the purpose of them.

I don’t want to drill, so can I just buy a hanging strap (5x failing limit) and a spring and run it over this plank to hold a punching bag weighing 70lbs? Or is this not gonna hold that weight and is there some other recommended option? I am new to this stuff, so really looking for some easier yet safe installation method.

[image]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: It's rare for easy to be safe when dealing with 70lbs of weight.

Answer (score -2):

It looks good. Just add a couple screws if it looks like the nails are loosening.

The problem with punching bags is not the weight, but the constant movement, pulling and yanking on the chain. Think of the difference between a drill and an impact wrench. Yes, you can do something more permanent, using 2x8s and lag bolts, but then you are risking splitting those joists. If this were my home, I'd hang the punching bag to that 2x6 in the picture, and if that fails, I'd take it as a sign to find another place to practice your MMA skills.

Comment: Screws should be added _before_ the nails loosen. They don't have a lot of pullout strength in a vertical arrangement like this, and when they let go it can be sudden.